TypeScript Exhaustive Type Checking for Dynamic Form Fields Not Working as Expected
I am working on a TypeScript solution to ensure exhaustive type-checking for dynamic form fields. The goal is to make sure that all required fields defined in an interface are included in the form configuration (I'm 90% there). While the first example works as expected, the second example should throw a type error because it is missing a required field, but no error is thrown. Here is a TsPlay link or my code below

interface IUser {
    fName: string;
    mName: string;
    lName: string;
}

function dynamicFormFor<T extends object>() {
    return function <U extends readonly SpecialInput<T>[]>(
        props: U & (ValidateFields<T, U> extends true ? {} : { error: "Missing fields" })
    ): { props: U; } {
        return { props, };
    };
}

const userForm = dynamicFormFor<IUser>()([
    {
        fields: [{ id: '1', name: 'fName', label: 'First Name' }],
        layouts: [{ fields: [{ id: '2', name: 'mName', label: 'Middle Name' }, { id: '3', name: 'lName', label: 'Last Name' }] }],
    },
]);

const invalidUserForm = dynamicFormFor<IUser>()([
    {
        fields: [{ id: '1', name: 'fName', label: 'First Name' }],
        layouts: [{ fields: [{ id: '2', name: 'mName', label: 'Middle Name' }] }],
    },
]); 

const invalidUserFormEmptyLayouts = dynamicFormFor<IUser>()([
    {
        fields: [{ id: '1', name: 'fName', label: 'First Name' }],
    },
]); 

How can I adjust the type definitions and constraints to ensure that TypeScript correctly throws a type error when required fields are missing from the form configuration? This includes weird behavior where having empty fields will also pass all missing errors.

This is a quite complicated example and unlikely to be minimal. I'd say from my reading through this that you require e11FormFor's returned function to infer literal types for the name properties of the subproperties of (see how hard this is to describe? oh well) the input. You can use a const type parameter as shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

It works as expected.  Thanks .

I'll write an answer when I get a chance, probably not until tomorrow (it's late in my time zone)

Your problem doesn't seem to be with the types (although they are quite complex, especially for a Stack Overflow question) but with how TypeScript infers the generic type argument for U when you call the function returned from e11FormFor().  You require the name properties to be string literal types like "fName", but if you check, TypeScript is inferring just string. TypeScript's inference algorithm is heuristic; quite often people want a value like {name: "fName"} to be inferred as type {name: string} and not {name: "fName"}, so the heuristics work that way.
In cases where you have a generic type parameter that TypeScript infers from an argument too widely, you can often fix it by making it a const type parameter. This is similar to using an as const assertion in the function argument, which gives TypeScript a hint that you want narrow literal types.  So if you have function f<T>(x: T){} and you call f({name: "fName"}), you can change it to function f<const T>(x: T){} and it will behave like you called f({name: "fName"} as const).
For your example code that looks like
function e11FormFor<T extends object>(dynamicFormOptions?: DynamicFormGroupsOptions) {
    return function <const U extends readonly SpecialInput<T>[]>(
        //           ^^^^^       
        props: U & (ValidateFields<T, U> extends true ? {} : { error: "Missing fields" })
    ): { props: U; dynamicFormOptions?: DynamicFormGroupsOptions } {
        return { props, dynamicFormOptions };
    };
}

And then your examples behave as desired.
Playground link to code
